# Rails: 'Could not find table' in a many-to-many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two tables set up in a many-to-many relationship: Incidents and Users.  When a user is logged in, and they view the /incidents page (the index), I want to display all the incidents they are associated with.  Unfortunately, the following error occurs:

```
Could not find table 'incidents_users'
```

It seems rails is looking for the table 'incidents_users', when I actually created the table 'users_incidents'.  'users_incidents' simply holds the user_id and incident_id.

Am I missing something obvious?  I'm relatively new to rails, so the problem could be something simple that I've overlooked.

Here is the relevant section of the incidents_controller.rb

```
# GET /incidents
# GET /incidents.xml
def index
  @incidents = current_user.incidents

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @incidents }
  end
end
```

Here is the relevant section of the index.html.erb

```
<% for incident in @incidents %>
  <tr>
    <td><%=h incident.other_id %></td>
    <td><%=h incident.title %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', [@customer, incident] %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_customer_incident_path(@customer, incident) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', [@customer, incident], :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Thanks!  Please let me know if more information would be helpful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your join table has to be called `incidents_users` because the Rails' convention when using a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association is that the table name is derived from the lexical order of the class names of the models that comprise the association.

From the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#M001836):

> So a join between Developer and
>   Project will give the default join
>   table name of "developers_projects"
>   because "D" outranks "P". Note that
>   this precedence is calculated using
>   the < operator for String. This means
>   that if the strings are of different
>   lengths, and the strings are equal
>   when compared up to the shortest
>   length, then the longer string is
>   considered of higher lexical
>   precedence than the shorter one. For
>   example, one would expect the tables
>   "paper_boxes" and "papers" to generate
>   a join table name of
>   "papers_paper_boxes" because of the
>   length of the name "paper_boxes", but
>   it in fact generates a join table name
>   of "paper_boxes_papers".

Note that the table name can be overridden using the `:join_table` option when specifying the association, so:

```
class Incident < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :join_table => 'users_incidents'
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :incidents, :join_table => 'users_incidents'
end
```

—It's generally best just to go with the Rails' conventions though, unless you've a particular reason that's preventing you.

Comment: That simple, huh?  Thanks! :)

Comment: Wow, thanks for the update!  I'm slowly learning how to understand the official API documentation.  I really appreciate your help.